# Import a local bash file into another bash file

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, unix

I have `var.sh`

```
name="John"
age="29"
```

I also have `main.sh`

```
eval "var.sh"
echo "My name is $name"
```

When I run, I kept getting

```
⚡️  Desktop  bash main.sh 
main.sh: line 1: var.sh: command not found
My name is
```

What is the best practice to import a local bash file into another bash file ?

Is there way that will work on Mac OS X, Linux and Windows ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`eval` is not meant for importing a script into another.  You need the `source` builtin:

```
source var.sh
```

which is synonymous to:

```
. var.sh
```

`eval` is throwing the error for one or both of these reasons:

- var.sh is not executable
- var.sh is executable but current directory is not in the PATH

Even if we address both of these issues, `eval` will spawn a shell to run `var.sh` which means all the variables set inside `var.sh` are forgotten once `eval` finishes and that's not what you want.

---

Output of `help source`:

> ```
> source: source filename [arguments]
>
> Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
>
> Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
> entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
> If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
> when FILENAME is executed.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
> FILENAME cannot be read.
> ```